# Correct for temporal autocorrelation in a GLM

Tags: glm, autocorrelation

I'm running a GLM to test the effect of stage(adult or nymph) and time (24h,48h,72h) on the mortality. I checked for autocorrelation using acf and the result indicated that there was indeed autocorrelation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXEOw.png)

When I tried to solve this with the function:
gls(Mortality~Time*Stage, data=data, correlation = corAR1(form=~Time))

It gives the following error:
Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[i]], ...) :
covariate must have unique values within groups for "corAR1" objects

The values within each time point are not unique since more values are attributed to one time point.

How can I solve this so I can still correct for autocorrelation?